# Oracle Not exists inside not exists

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

Guys when I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM big_table big
WHERE sum_number = 1
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM smal_table smal
                  WHERE other_number = big.other_number
                )
```

I get 4 resuslts, but when I run this one

```
SELECT * FROM big_table big
WHERE sum_number = 1
 AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM smal_table smal
                  WHERE other_number = big.other_number
                  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                    FROM and_another_table another
                                    WHERE and_another_number = big.and_another_number
                                 )
                )
```

I get all lines from big_table.
Does anyone have the slightest idea why this happens?
I want to do a query that shows me all lines from big_table that does not exist in the smal_table but if it exists in the small table I only want the lines that are not in the and_another_table
Can anyone help me please?

EDIT: I want the lines from the big_table that are not in small_table plus the lines from big_table that are on the small_table but not in the and_another_table

Comment: The first inner select gets many matches, so you only get the 4 records having no match in that set. The second inner select has one more criteria to fulfill so it finds fewer records, so there are of course more records in the big table having no match this time. Please explain again what exactly you want to select. I don't understand your explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic is that you want the rows from the big table that are not in either the small table or the another table.  If so, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM big_table big
WHERE sum_number = 1 AND
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM small_table smal
                   WHERE other_number = big.other_number
                  ) OR
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM and_another_table another
                   WHERE and_another_number = big.and_another_number
                  )
      );
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment below, the `where` clause would be:

```
WHERE sum_number = 1 AND
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM small_table smal
                   WHERE other_number = big.other_number
                  ) OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM and_another_table another
               WHERE and_another_number = big.and_another_number
              )
      );
```

Comment: No, I want the lines from the big_table that are not in small_table plus the lines from big_table that are on the small_table but not in the and_another_table

Comment: @user3360301 . . . The question says "if it exists in the small table I only want the lines that are not in the and_another_table".  I at least am confused as to the correct logic.  But, based on your comment, you can change the last `not exists` to `exists`.